# Did the city search data from the Facebook Ads API suddenly change?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

The City Search call used to return a response where each city had the form:

```
{
  "name": "Dublin, CA", 
  "key": 220522764, 
  "subtext": "CA, United States"
}
```

Now the API returns:

```
{
  "name": "Dublin", 
  "key": 220522764, 
  "subtext": "California, United States"
}
```

The first format is still listed in the API docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/

Is this a permanent change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our apologies for this change - we've reverted this change and will take precaution to avoid these things in the future. Thank you for the report.

We've added another parameter to use in your query if you want to get the city name without the state. Documentation updated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, last week. No warning from Facebook.